# Writing Function involving ServiceController

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to read each line of text from the file outputted from this block.
Each line is then used with the service controller to output a list of services running on that computer.

```
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
    'Name place to write file to
    Dim strFile As String = "C:\DomainUsers.txt"
    Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)

    'get list of all users on domain and write to file
    de.Path = "WinNT://domain.com"
    'Write each user to a text file as List
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        MsgBox("Writing all Users to Memory, Click OK and wait for Window to Close")
        For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
            sw.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Next
        Console.Clear()
    End Using

    'Reopen File and read each line
    'Return List of Processes for each User in Overwritefashion to New Version of File
    Using sr As New StreamReader(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.Open))
        Dim InstalledServices As List(Of String) = GetInstalledServices(sr.ReadLine.Trim)
    End Using

End Sub

'Lost as to how to go about using this function...
Function GetInstalledServices(ByVal Computer As String) As List(Of String)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check it, but it'll be something like  ...

```
Function GetInstalledServices(ByVal Computer As String) As List(Of String)

  Dim RetVal as New List(Of String)
  Dim scServices() As ServiceController()

  Try
      scServices = ServiceController.GetServices(Computer)

  For Each Svc as ServiceController In scServices

    RetVal.Add(Svc.ServiceName)

  Next

  Catch Ex as Exception
  End Try


  Return RetVal

End Function
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says I couldnt connect to remote machine. Now to add something that makes it move on if it is unable to connect. Thanks for the help